# Dynamic hive view creation

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have 10 hive tables, few columns might be similar in few tables, I need to union them into one table. I was writing Union all statements.

Now, these columns in these 10 tables might change . how to create the Union all query dynamically based on the tables.

```
CREATE VIEW comb_view AS
SELECT col11, col12, col13,.....
From
(SELECT col11,col12,NULL col13 from tab1
UNION ALL
SELECT col11,NULL col12, col13 from tab2
.
.
.
.
) c
```

ensuring the position and data type.

Comment: Hi you an achieve  it by query from HIVE Metastore get column of tables and then create dynamic query in hive .

Comment: You mean, creating the dynamic query in Hive Metastore which is mysql in this case. Can we do it with HQL?